# Erlang performance profiling using fprof in CPU time

Tags: erlang, profiling

I am trying to have a better performance visualization of my software using fprof. However, the default is measured using wall clock but I want to measure it with cpu time. Hence, I run the following command on the shell but I get an error. Could not really find the reason why it fails on the Internet or erlang documentation. Does anybody have any hints?

```
% fprof:trace([start, {cpu_time, true}]).
{error,not_supported}
```

Comment: You on either OSX or Windows per chance?

Answer (score 2):

fprof's cpu_time flag is translated to trace's cpu_timestamp as showed in the code snippet above:

According to http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#trace-3:

> cpu_timestamp
>
> A global trace flag for the Erlang node that makes all trace timestamps be in CPU time, not wallclock. It is only allowed with `PidSpec==all`. If the host machine operating system does not support high resolution CPU time measurements, `trace/3` exits with `badarg`.

So, if the call `erlang:trace(all, true, [cpu_timestamp])` returns a badarg exception it means that this feature is unsupported on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is from file `fprof.erl`, It shows where the error message comes from. But I don't know how to continue find the source code of `erlang:trace`. It may be written by c. If trace's source code can be found, the secret can be unveiled.

```
trace_on(Procs, Tracer, {V, CT}) ->
    case case CT of
         cpu_time ->
         try erlang:trace(all, true, [cpu_timestamp]) of _ -> ok
         catch
             error:badarg -> {error, not_supported} ％％ above error message is shown here
         end;
         wallclock -> ok
     end
    of ok ->
        MatchSpec = [{'_', [], [{message, {{cp, {caller}}}}]}],
        erlang:trace_pattern(on_load, MatchSpec, [local]),
        erlang:trace_pattern({'_', '_', '_'}, MatchSpec, [local]),
        lists:foreach(
          fun (P) ->
              erlang:trace(P, true, [{tracer, Tracer} | trace_flags(V)])
          end,
          Procs),
        ok;
    Error ->
        Error
    end.
```